# What's the significance of the watermelon in Sora no Otoshimono?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

In Sora no Otoshimono, Ikaros carries around a watermelon like a pet and likes watermelons and pretty much anything else round.  At one point she even has a watermelon garden and attacks all the bugs that get near the melons.

What's the significance of the watermelon and why does she carry one around?

Comment: i remember my teacher telling me that the wattermelon (in asia) simbolizes Verginity... just thought i should throw that out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is no significance.

It is just a character trait that she really likes watermelons. Probably for their smooth and round shape.

Comment: Seems like the staff have said that there is a reason but it hasn't been revealed yet, according to the #1 answer at http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1249494757 which is basically asking the same question.

Comment: My Japanese is a bit rough but it looks like it says something about making her happy because it's round and she likes to pat round things like people's heads.  That sound about right?

Comment: @MCeley The part I was referring to says "But the director says there is a deeper meaning. If you buy the DVD, there is an extra feature with the director's comments. He says there is a perfectly good reason that Alpha (Ikaros) likes round things."

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand of the anime, she likes being patted on her head by her master. Since patting something round reminds her of the times her master pats her, she may simply be reliving that memory.

Comment: (By the way, this is the same as in the Yahoo answer that atlantiza posted).

Answer (score 0):

I think Ikaros likes watermelon not just because it is round and reminds her of herself when she is being pet, but she also is in a situation where she might be under a lot of stress without even knowing it (she is trying to get taken back to her original master), and this is her way to cope with it.

But this is a more realistic theory, so this probably isn't even close to the idea the producers had when making this decision.